# How to select distinct values on a join select?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have this bit of code:

```
def self.table_with_finished_or_no_orders
  Table.joins("left join orders 
     on orders.table_id=tables.id")
    .where("orders.finished = ? OR orders.table_id is NULL",  true)
end
```

But I'd like to select only `DISTINCT` tables. How should I modify this?

**Edit**

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT `tables`.* FROM `tables` 
 left join orders on orders.table_id=tables.id 
 WHERE (orders.finished = 1 OR orders.table_id is NULL)
```

Comment: Could you post your complete SQL query as generated by this statement

Comment: Try `Table.joins("left join orders on orders.table_id=tables.id").where("orders.finished = ? OR orders.table_id is NULL",  true).uniq!`

Comment: If that doesn't work. try `Table.includes(:orders).where("orders.finished = ? OR orders.table_id is NULL",  true)`

Comment: Could you rename your variables so they are not reserved keywords: I get lost in your question that you want "DISTINCT tables". Too many time the term tables in there....